# Android Best Practice for Continuous loops in onCreate

Tags: java, android, loops

I’m working on a project that needs to have infinite loop that is active when the activity is active.

This loop:

- Receive messages from a connected Thread for blue tooth
- Must send messages out to same thread.
- Handler the messages

I tried a “while(true)” loop but the I found that the onClick Listeners had to be in the loop. This concerned me if one the onClick listeners broke out of the while loop.

Is that OK?

So is it best type of loop to use?

Update ====================

Here is what I did.

```js
Handler handlerTimeLoop = new Handler();
Runnable runnableTimerLoop;
int delay = 2*1000; //Delay for 2 seconds.  One second = 1000 milliseconds.
int counterLoop;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(layout.activity_operate);


    handlerTimeLoop.postDelayed( runnableTimerLoop = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
          //do something
          counterLoop++;
          Log.d(TAG,"Looped: " + counterLoop);
          
          //Start next delay
          handlerTimeLoop.postDelayed(runnableTimerLoop, delay);
       }
    }, delay);//END of "Timer Loop"

    //Button Listeners =========================================================================
    buttonListeners();
}//END of "onCreate()"
```

Comment: None of that sounds like it requires a continuous loop, just listeners.

Comment: Generally, you wouldn't want to run an infinite loop within onCreate. This will block your app on the main thread. Android OS would probably give an error/alert and close your app. OnCreate is intended to set up required resources for your application. If you MUST run an infinite loop and not implement event listeners then I'd look into the Android Runnable and Android Thread classes. In a new thread you can run your infinite server loop without blocking your main thread. Bluetooth is a tricky beast glhf

Comment: My background is more firmware coding.  I may be taking the wrong approach. 
So, can someone expand on what type of listeners that could replace a loop?
There would be a message sent and a response expected. The loop was going to use a switch-case to provide the proper action for the received message.